# Amazon Redshift: How can I convert a 15 char Salesforce Id value into an 18 char Id value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-redshift

I'm Holding SalesForce Data on Amazon Redshift DB.
I would like to create a function on Redshift that will convert SalesForce 15 Char ID to 18 Char ID. I found this topic that gives a direction of how to:

[salesforce id - How can I convert a 15 char Id value into an 18 char Id value? - Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/how-can-i-convert-a-15-char-id-value-into-an-18-char-id-value)

But non of this functions is working  on Redshift and I cannot use that \ create a similar function on Amazon Redshift DB. (Have to say I'm pretty new @ this.

Can someone have a code that works on Redshift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooh, nice question!

I found some conversion code here:

- [Salesforce.com ID Converter allows you to convert 15 digit, case-sensitive IDs to an 18 digit, case-safe version for use with Salesforce.com records.](https://gist.github.com/KorbenC/7356677)
- [sf15to18/sf15to18.py at master · mslabina/sf15to18](https://github.com/mslabina/sf15to18/blob/master/sf15to18.py)

I used that to create an Amazon Redshift User-Defined Function (UDF):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_salesforce_15_to_18 (id varchar)
  RETURNS varchar
STABLE
AS $$

# Code comes from: https://gist.github.com/KorbenC/7356677

for i in xrange(0, 3):
  flags = 0

  for x in xrange(0,5):
    c = id[i*5+x]

    #add flag if c is uppercase
    if c.isupper():
      flags = flags + (1 << x)

  if flags <= 25:
    id += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[flags]
  else:
    id += '012345'[flags - 26]

return id

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Run it with:

```
SELECT f_salesforce_15_to_18 ('500A000000D34Xf')
```

It seems to work, but please test it!